# Integrate OData pentesting tool to ZAP add-on

Tags: sql-injection, zap

We are currently working on a ZAP (Zed Attack Proxy) add-on designed to facilitate the pentesting of our new framework. 
Our solution is using OData so we were wondering if their was existing tools that we could have integrate in the add-on. I heard about OyeData, but it doesn't look like you can easily call it from another application. SQLmap would have been easy to call from our add-on, for instance, but it does not support OData testing.

Have you ever encountered an testing tool that could fit our requirements ? (Perform SQL injection through OData, and be "simple" to call/integrate from an external application ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZAP already supports OData in the spider and active scanner, which means that all existing active scan rules (such as SQLi ones) will work with OData:

- https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpStartConceptsSpider#odata-atom-format
- https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsOptionsAscaninput#build-in-input-vector-handlers

Having said that I'm sure theres more that can be done, so be very interested to hear of what else your add-on will be able to do :)

Comment: Your answer lead me to perform more tests and ask my colleagues more details about the situation. I think that I misunderstood the problem and, indeed, ZAP already supports SQLi in OData. The issue comes from another layer, which is too specific for ZAP to cover it. As I am intern and working on an intern tool, I fear that I will not be able to give more details on the add-on. Sorry, I am not sure of what I can say and what I can't say so I don't want to take any risk :)

Comment: Not a problem - we often find people using ZAP for specific things that they cant talk about :)